# How to get node information from view in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I created a custom block to display node author information - author name, published date, and category - in Drupal 8.  I added the block to both node default and teaser displays.  I am using following to get the node object:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

It works fine when I'm on the default display (full node page) but it returns empty in teaser mode (views).  I am thinking because the views do not have parameter information.

How can I get access to each node object from view display?

Thank you.

Seong Bae

Comment: You could check the node type (content type) settings and look at manage display and look at what settings you have on teaser display.

Comment: Hi Sanjok. I'm not sure if I follow.  Do you have any code examples?

Comment: If I understand correctly its configuring settings rather than code. So say if your content type is `Articles` then on the admin menu go to `structure->content types` and on your `article` content type click `manage display`, there on the top right below the tabs you can see the displays `default. teaser ` etc. If you want more displays there is Custom display settings at the bottom. Then on your `teaser` mode check if your required fields is set to hidden, then select the format you want.